# Is there a way to check incorrect table names (or aliases) in MySQL Stored Procedures without executing/calling them?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, tablename

**Background**:
I'm having to move from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8. I do not have access to `lower_case_table_names` (which is set to 0). I have ~200 stored procedures, in which the table names (e.g. `my_table_1`) and their aliases in queries/DML statements (e.g. `mt1`) are NOT case-sensitive.

So I have stored procedures with statements like: `SELECT mt1.column1, MT1.column2 from my_table_1 MT1 where MT1.column3=100;`. In MySQL 5.7, this is a valid statement; but not in MySQL 8.

I am about to embark on a project to update all the stored procedures with the correct case.

**Questions**:

1. Is there an easy way to achieve this update?

   - The table names don't have any prefixes/suffixes to identify them uniquely. For example, `school` could be a table name, not `t_school`.
   - Also, aliases are very generic (e.g. `s`, `c` etc.)
2. Even if I complete this task, is there a way to check whether the updates are done correctly, without executing each procedure?

   - I noticed that queries get flagged as wrong when run standalone, but not when compiled as part of a stored procedure. For example, if a table name is `my_table_1` then `SELECT * from MY_TABLE_1` fails when executed as a standalone query, but if it is part of a stored procedure, the procedure gets compiled successfully (i.e. its DDL gets updated successfully). But calling the procedure causes an error.

Comment: why are you moving to case sensitive? is there a specific reason?

Comment: I don't know of a way to automate this, because there are too many edge cases. Visual inspection followed by testing is both the fastest and most effective method.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell DO's managed MySQL DB does not allow changing, or even initializing, the `lower_case_table_name` value, which defaults to 0. This requires case-sensitive table names.